# Does Blender allow to perform operations on multiple objects at once?

Tags: interface

Let's say five objects are parented to the same 6th object. Is it possible to remove the parenting links at once. Selecting all children and removing the parent doesn't work:

[image]

Only the "active" object is un-parented.

That's curious since the inverse operation, parenting multiple objects to the same parent, is possible at once.

Comment: with alt P > Clear Parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing inverse operation to parenting. Modifying a parameter of active object (properties display active object) only influences that object.

Operators can operate on selections, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> do.

If there is no operator to do it on multiple objects then <kbd>RMB</kbd> on the field > *Copy to Selected*. Works on most parameters in general.

Comment: So 'Copy to Selected', or, but only when available, a specific menu entry working on multiple objects, like 'Parent Set' / 'Parent Clear'. What is implicit in your answer (thanks) is that 'Parent' field setting and menu entry '3D>Object>Parent>Object' are NOT equivalent, contrary to usually a bit quickly explained. They are working on different sets of objects. Those subtleties increase the difficulty to learn Blender, I believe.